# Use Mac Sleepimage

Tags: recovery

I need to access a Pages document I lost that was open in my last "sleepimage" (3 days old) file.
How can I use/open this file to access what is in it aka the content I lost ..?

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Using Mac OS 10.7.5

Comment: Which Mac are you using?

Comment: Macbook Air 13in from Mid 2011, OS 10.7.5

Comment: If it was 3 days ago I am afraid it is lost (overwritten)

Comment: What I meant is that that is the sleepimage i have and it is the one I want to use - I can see the file and the timestamp on it; I just have no idea how to open it ...

Comment: Do you use Time Machine or have it on in System Preferences?

Comment: I don't use Time Machine, it is on system preference; I wish I was using Time Machine; the recovery would have been so much easier :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the sleep image is of little use to you. 
This is technically the complete memory registers dumped to a signed encrypted file. Reverse engineering a document from this raw fragmented data is extremely unlikely; there is no filesystem here to browse as it where.

You may have more success taking a look at your iCloud raw content?

https://developer.icloud.com